# Como obtener las compras de cada usuario con 1 consulta

Tags: php, mysql

mi duda es la siguiente:

Tengo una tabla llamada "compradores" y otra "compras", quisiera listar las compras que hizo cada comprador, es decir que por cada usuario que tengo en la tabla "compradores" me muestre sus respectivas compras que tengo en la tabla "compras" existe alguna forma de obtener ese resultado en 1 consulta?.

La estructura de mis tablas son:

Compradores (id,nombre,apellido,email)
Compras (id,id_comprador,articulo,cantidad)

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Y que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Por ahora nada porque no se como hacerlo... lo unico que se me ocurre es hacerlo con muchas consultas... ua primer consulta para selecccionar todos los compradores, luego con un bucle ir haciendo 1 consulta por cada comprador... :/

Comment: Por favor agrega al menos una idea de como lo harías, en la pregunta. Si puedes mostrar algo de código, mejor.

Comment: y pq no pruebas eso? lo que dijiste no parece que este mal... no sabria que estas buscando mejorar si ni siquiera puedes con eso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un `INNER JOIN` puedes hacerlo fácilmente:

```
SELECT
    Compradores.nombre,
    Compras.* 
FROM 
    Compradores
    INNER JOIN Compras ON(Compradores.id = Compras.id_comprador)
ORDER BY 
    Compradores.nombre ASC
```

Esto te mostrará todos los compradores y sus compras realizadas.

Comment: Me funciono a la perfeccion... ¿es posible hacer que las compras se ordenen aleatoriamente?. Gracias

Comment: Nunca lo he hecho, pero parece que se puede realizar cambiando las últimas dos líneas de la consulta por: `ORDER BY Compradores.nombre ASC, rand()`. Me cuentas como te va.

Comment: Opino que no deberían de responder a alguien que hace una pregunta tan simple sin ningún intento de hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta hacer esta consulta utilizando joins.

Puedes aprender un poco en este [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

```
select * from compradores join compras on compras.id_comprador = compradores.id where compradores.id = 1;
```

Comment: Opino que no deberían de responder a alguien que hace una pregunta tan simple sin ningún intento de hacerlo.

Comment: Si pero el hecho de ayudar no significa que sea algo negativo a demás puse un link con documentación para su aprendizaje si diste como no útil mi respuesta creo que tu argumento no es válido.

Answer (score -1):

La tablas como las tienes diseñadas ahora te traerán problemas, uno de ellos es la redundancia de datos, lo cual hace crecer el tamaño de la BD y la hace difícil de mantener.

Por ejemplo, en la tabla `compras` no debe estar el nombre del `articulo`, sino que debes tener una tabla dedicada a los artículos.

En base de datos las tablas pueden relacionarse por claves, que son generalmente valores numéricos que identifican un único valor en la otra tabla.

Tomando el mismo ejemplo de la tabla compras, si en ella incluyes el nombre del artículo, cada vez que compran algo tendrías que escribir el nombre... noooo, mejor, pones una columna `id_articulo` que apunte a cada artículo en su tabla.

Luego las tablas se unen usando la sentencia `JOIN`. Hay varios tipos de `JOIN` aquí mismo encontrarás excelentes respuestas sobre ello.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de diseño que podría servirte de orientación.

La **Query 1** se puede modificar para obtener cualquier otro resultado, aplicando contadores, filtros, agrupación, ordenarla por cualquiera de las columnas, etc.

[**`DEMO SQL Fiddle`**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c569fb/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE compradores
    (`id_comprador` int, `nombre` varchar(70))
;

INSERT INTO compradores
    (`id_comprador`, `nombre`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Pedro'),
    (2, 'Santiago'),
    (3, 'Juan')
;

CREATE TABLE compras
    (`id_compra` int, `id_comprador` int, `id_articulo` int, `cantidad` int, `fecha` date)
;

INSERT INTO compras
    (`id_compra`, `id_comprador`, `id_articulo`,  `cantidad`,  `fecha`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, 30, '2017-05-01'),
    (2, 3, 2, 25, '2017-02-11'),
    (3, 2, 2, 90, '2017-03-01'),
    (4, 3, 1, 15, '2017-03-08'),
    (5, 1, 2, 01, '2017-04-20'),
    (6, 3, 2, 23, '2017-05-06'),
    (7, 1, 1, 40, '2017-05-03'),
    (8, 2, 1, 76, '2017-02-22')
;


CREATE TABLE articulos
    (`id_articulo` int, `articulo` varchar(70))
;

INSERT INTO articulos
    (`id_articulo`, `articulo`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Pan'),
    (2, 'Arroz'),
    (3, 'Caviar')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  cm.nombre, a.articulo, c.cantidad, c.fecha
FROM
  compras c  
    LEFT JOIN compradores cm ON c.id_comprador = cm.id_comprador
    LEFT JOIN articulos a ON c.id_articulo = a.id_articulo
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c569fb/1/0)**:

```
|   nombre | articulo | cantidad |                      fecha |
|----------|----------|----------|----------------------------|
|    Pedro |      Pan |       30 |      May, 01 2017 00:00:00 |
|    Pedro |      Pan |       40 |      May, 03 2017 00:00:00 |
| Santiago |      Pan |       76 | February, 22 2017 00:00:00 |
|     Juan |      Pan |       15 |    March, 08 2017 00:00:00 |
|    Pedro |    Arroz |        1 |    April, 20 2017 00:00:00 |
| Santiago |    Arroz |       90 |    March, 01 2017 00:00:00 |
|     Juan |    Arroz |       25 | February, 11 2017 00:00:00 |
|     Juan |    Arroz |       23 |      May, 06 2017 00:00:00 |
```

Comment: Opino que no deberían de responder a alguien que hace una pregunta tan simple sin ningún intento de hacerlo. A. Cedano eres grande en el foro, tu mas muchos no deberías de fomentar esa clase de preguntas.

Comment: @PabloContreras Gracias. La idea era explicar al OP algunos conceptos básicos sobre cómo combinar las tablas en su diseño, pues vi que empezó por muy mal camino, mezclando tablas que deberían estar separadas. Considero injusto que la respuesta haya sido votada negativamente, parece que en esSO hay quienes no aprecian las buenas respuestas. Saludos.

Comment: Tus respuestas siempre son grandes, admirables para mi, pero solamente el usuario hablo de su idea, no de si lo intento o no. Siempre todos intentamos algo, yo no soy excelente programando pero me hecho mis arrancones de pelos hasta que ya no hallo la solución publico acá lo que llevo y por mas bobo que pueda ser la solución, con pena publico lo que llevo, por que acá muchos son muchísimo mejores programando que yo, también supongo que por experiencia.

Comment: @PabloContreras  Yo publico siempre con la idea de que pueda servir no sólo al OP, sino también a otros. Además, no tengo reparo en comentar si algo está mal en el diseño. De hecho, la mayoría de problemas vienen porque en el fondo el diseño no es el más adecuado, entonces se van buscando soluciones por las ramas. De todos modos gracias por tus comentarios. Lo tendré en cuenta para el futuro.

Comment: Ok disculpa lo malo. Saludos :D